# how can i find unique conversation from table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have this table:

[Messages table]

[image: 1]

I need to find the number of uniqe conversation -
conversation is define as senderid sent msg to reciverid, and reciverid has replied (no matter how many times or the thread length, it will be count as 1 conversation).
so if senderid = 1, reeiver id =2
and in the next row senderid = 2 and reciever id =1 this is one conversation (till the end of time)
Im really stock and not sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` to create unique combinations of the 2 ids and aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEAST(m1.senderid, m1.receiverid), GREATEST(m1.senderid, m1.receiverid)) counter
FROM Messages m1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Messages m2 WHERE (m2.receiverid, m2.senderid) = (m1.senderid, m1.receiverid))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02302678e3ffaafd314bec10a3a6f868).
Results (for your sample data):

> | counter |
> | --- |
> | 2 |

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I don't think this will work as it will only count how many conversations have begun, not necessarily if the receiver replied.

Comment: You are correct. There are only 2 conversations in the data ive attached. Senderid 1 sent msg to reciverid 3 but he didnt send back a msg therfore it is not counted as conversation. Hope i ws able to explain myself.

Comment: I think 1/2 is a valid conversation and 2/3 is a valid conversation, but 1/3 is not a valid one since 3 never replied to 1.  That's why I used a self join to ensure they replied to each other.

Comment: @lennyb if by conversation you mean that there is a reply from receiverid then see my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using a `self join` with `least` and `greatest` to get your desired results:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select distinct least(m1.senderid, m2.senderid), greatest(m1.receiverid, m2.receiverid)
    from messages m1
        join messages m2 on m1.senderid = m2.receiverid and m1.receiverid = m2.senderid
) t
```